# The standard midi digital audio storage formats

Tags: audio, format, audio-recording

I would like to implement an 8-bit audio clip. Basically just some notes that are run through some modulations and such. I am new so don't know the terminology too well.

What I'm wondering in order to do this is, the typical/standard format you store your audio sequence in. I know about all the audio formats and lossy/lossless, but these seem to apply to *recording audio signals from the environment*, rather than *generating the audio from within*.

When the audio is generated, it seems instead of storing it as the final output sound waves, you could instead store it as the midi sequence or as the notes and intensity, or some waves of some sort. This way you can build a music/sound editor, and save your file, and return to the file with your notes in place.

[Midi sequences in the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ4Ey.png)

Wondering how this is typically done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MIDI the sounds are stored as notes and durations for voices(instruments).  When they are played, the sound card(or a software program) generates the appropriate waveforms to be played on the speaker.

MIDI files offer much smaller files than its MP3 or WAV counterparts, at the expense of speech and sound variation.

Not all implementations of MIDI make the same sounds. A professional MIDI synthesizer could generate waveforms for instruments by using captured sounds of real instruments; compared to the typical PC implementation of a generic instrument.

A similar method was used in most 8-bit games to generate music.

Comment: Wondering if it's just a `.MID` or `.MIDI` file extension, or something else.

Comment: The ones I have seen are `.MID` files.